# Laravel 4 - Custom auth.basic verify credential using custom code

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

At the moment, when I add a `before` filter to my route like this:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('front');
})->before('auth.basic');
```

and visit my test app (*e.g. http://domain.com*), I see the following in Chrome:

[image]

What I'd like to is; when the user enters the username and password and clicks the "Login In" button - run a custom credential validation routine to verify the entered details.

By custom validation routine, I mean to make a request to external API and check if entered credentials are valid and then return `true`/`false` to the basic auth attempt.

Is this possible? Does this involve writing a custom `auth.basic` driver?

Answer (score 1):

While using `auth.basic` authentication in laravel, it uses the HTTP basic authentication for the website, meaning that it asks and appends username and password in the HTTP header of the packets. Saying that, browsers are prepared to take care of HTTP basic authentication and does it before processing the body of the packet, meaning that you see the pop-up shown.

use laravel's `auth` instead. It checks if the user is already logged in by the registered `Auth::check()` in session, and if not, redirects to your login url and stores the intended url in session to redirect after authentication is passed. See [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security).